# Styling the progressbar in ActionbarSherlock

Tags: android, progress-bar, actionbarsherlock

The horizontal progressbar in ActionbarSherlock is too thin, and is very hard to see. How can I style it to be a few pixels thicker?

I've tried applying a custom style in styles.xml by inhering the style from Widget.Sherlock.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal, but it's really confusing and I don't know which properties to set.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of attempting to make the `ProgressBar` thicker, try using a color that contrasts from the `ActionBar` color to make it stand out, and be noticible.

That's what I did with my app. I have a grey `ActionBar`, with a bright red `ProgressBar`.

Hope this helps!