# Set progress bar color in actionbar sherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-progressbar

How can we set color of the progress bar in ABS. By default it coming out to be blue in color, which looked perfect with dark theme. But when i use light theme it's almost not visible.

Which item in style of android:progressBarStyle i should override to change color. I want to achieve exactly the same described on this link [Styling the progressbar in ActionbarSherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687011/styling-the-progressbar-in-actionbarsherlock?answertab=active#tab-top).

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.
Instead of using action bar progress i added one `progressbar` element to my layout file. Then set the `xml` file as `progressdrawable` to `progress bar` with desired color.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="0"
        android:secondaryProgress="0" 
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"      
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

progressdrawable

```
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:centerColor="@color/progresscolor"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="@color/progresscolor"
                android:startColor="@color/progresscolor" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```